# importing java source into netbeans

Tags: debugging, netbeans-8

I need to quickly come up to speed on a java application written by another person in our organization.  There are 309 java source files and I'd like to bring the source into NetBeans 8, create the java classes, and step thru the source using the NetBeans debugger.  How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to find out what was original IDE the project was created. It might be possible by viewing files that are in the project root folder. NetBeans may know how to import e.g. Eclipse or maven project.